# format a flash drive to Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

Tags: macosx, format

Is it even possible to do that on Ubuntu? I need to format it to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) to install OSX and I don't have a Mac available :/ Could is even install the image with ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

gParted with [hfsprogs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hfsprogs/) can do this.

But it might have limitations since it is not native to Linux.

> The HFS+ file system used by Apple Computer for their Mac OS is supported by the Linux kernel.  Apple provides mkfs and fsck for HFS+
>   with the Unix core of their operating system, Darwin.
>
> This package is a port of Apple's tools for HFS+ filesystems.
>
> For users, HFS+ seems to be a good compromise to carry files between MacOS X and Linux Machines, as HFS+ doesn't suffer the
>   problems of FAT32 like:
>
> - huge space waste (in slack space as devices grow faster);
> - bility to create files that are more than 4GB in size (especially good for those working with multimedia and that need to carry large
>     ISO files);
> - ability to use case preserving (and even sensitivity!);
> - ability to use uid's and gid's on the filesystem. Users in general can enjoy such benefits since it is expected to have more HFS+ filesystems in use, as Apple has announced Macintoshes for ix86-64, besides the filesystem being already supported by PowerPC system since the beginning.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks. It could be helpful if i could "burn" the image to the flash drive as well. Could it be done?