# Bootable Mac USB with ISO Using Ubuntu

Tags: usb, macosx

I'm trying to use Ubuntu to create a Mac Boot USB using a Mac installation iso file. I tried Startup Disk Creator, but that won't recognise the iso file. Can anyone here point me in the right direction to achieving this?

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be done, easily.  I found a couple of examples for creating a Mac OSX install disk from Win10, but the big block for you is that the USB needs to be formatted in a manner that Ubuntu sort of supports:  Mac OSX extended (journaled). See (https://askubuntu.com/questions/441210/format-a-flash-drive-to-mac-os-extended-journaled).

Comment: If you have a Win 10 VM or system handy, you could try [https://pureinfotech.com/make-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-windows/](https://pureinfotech.com/make-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-windows/)

Comment: I'll see if I can do it in Win 10.